# How to make java restarts with receive word from keyboard

Tags: java

I want to ask the user if they want to play again when they finish a game. Currently, the only way for them to do that is to call the program again; however, I'd like to prompt the user for whether or not they'd like to play again once they finish a game.

```
public class Hangman
{

    Random r;
    GetData get;
    String[] words = {"eat","what" };
    String word; 
    boolean finished = false;
    int badGuessCount=0;  
    boolean [] foundLetters;   
    String entryWord =" ";  

    public Hangman()
    {
      r = new Random();
      get = new GetData();
      playAGame();
    }

    public void playAGame()
    { 

        word = words[r.nextInt(words.length)];

        foundLetters = new boolean[word.length()];

        while (!finished)
        {
            showGallows(); 
            showWord();
            getGuess();
            checkGuess();
             if (badGuessCount==6)
             {
                 System.out.print('\u000C');
                 showGallows();
                 System.out.println("Sorry, but you lost.");
                 System.out.println("The word was: "+word);
                 finished=true;
             }
        }
    }

    public void showGallows()
    {
        System.out.print('\u000C');
        if (badGuessCount==0)
           man_0();
        if (badGuessCount==1)
           man_1();
        if (badGuessCount==2)
           man_2();
        if (badGuessCount==3)
           man_3();
        if (badGuessCount==4)
           man_4();
        if (badGuessCount==5)
           man_5();
        if (badGuessCount==6)
           completedMan();



        System.out.println("\n");
    }

    public boolean showWord()
    {
         boolean goodGuess = false;
         char ch = entryWord.charAt(0);
         for (int lc=0; lc < word.length(); lc++)
             if (foundLetters[lc]==true)
             {
               System.out.print(word.charAt(lc)+" ");
             }
             else if (word.charAt(lc)==ch)
                  {
                      System.out.print(word.charAt(lc)+" ");
                      foundLetters[lc] = true;
                      goodGuess = true;
                   }
                   else
                       System.out.print("_ ");
         return goodGuess;
    }

    public void getGuess()
    {
         System.out.println("\n\n\nWhat letter do you want to guess?");
         System.out.println("Type the whole word to guess the word.");
         System.out.println("You have "+(6 - badGuessCount)+ "guess left.");
         System.out.print("Enter guess");
         entryWord = get.aWord();
    }

    public void checkGuess()
    {
        boolean goodGuess; 
        if (entryWord.length()>1)
        {
            if (entryWord.equals(word))
            {
                System.out.println("\n\nYes You won!");
                finished = true;
                System.out.println("close and run if you want to play again!");
                String pause = get.aWord();
            }       
    }
    else
    {
        showGallows();
        goodGuess = showWord();
        if (goodGuess)
        {
            System.out.println("\n\n\nGood guess");
            System.out.println("Press the Enter key to continue!");
            String pause = get.aWord();
        }
            else
            {
            badGuessCount++;
            System.out.println("\n\n\nBad guess!");
            System.out.println("Press the Enter key to continue!");
            String pause = get.aWord();
            }
        }

    }   

    //public void completedMan()


}
```

How can I prompt the user to play again, and then restart the game based on their input?

Comment: I want to restart my program this is code of my program when I play program finished I need to close and open to run it again but I want it restart  itself when they receive some word from my keyboard

Comment: So, write a loop - I don't understand what the problem is. Also, why are you using a bunch of `if` statements instead of `switch`?

Comment: I write a loop but It not restart

Comment: I can't play it again

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to put `playAGame();` itself inside a loop.

```
do
{
   playAGame();
} while (UserWantsToKeepPlaying());

private boolean UserWantsToKeepPlaying() {
    // Ask the user if they want to keep playing
}
```

I suggest a `do` - `while` loop because you'll always play the game at least once, and you (presumably) don't want to prompt the user to play again until after they finish playing a game.

Comment: I don't know about return I use that code but stuck at return program need something when use boolean

Answer (score 0):

error at while (UserWantsToKeepPlaying()); what I suppose to do

```
  do
  {
      playAGame();
  } while (UserWantsToKeepPlaying());
}

public boolean UserWantsToKeepPlaying(int number) 
{
  for (int i = 1; i > number; i--)
  if (number % i == 0 && i != number) return false;
  else return true;
  System.out.print("\n\n Play Again 'No' Press 0  Yes' Press 1 : ");
}
```